# Node.js npm dependencies in subfolder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-webkit

I have a project in which I use node-webkit. node-webkit allows npm packages to be used for developing desktop applications. I make use of grunt to build my application.

My folder structure looks like this at the moment:

```
project root
    node_modules/ (1)
    package.json  (1)
    App/
        node_modules/ (2)
        package.json  (2)
        bower.json
        bower_components/
        ... 
        controllers/
        filters/
        ...
        app.js
```

The npm dependencies for the application itself are kept within the App folder, but the **dev** dependencies for **building** the project are not related to the application source code, so i keep them in **node_modules (1)** inside the root folder. I also know that in a package.json file one can express dependencies and **dev** dependencies, exactly for this reason. I would rather have one package.json file in the root expressing ALL dependencies, including dev dependencies, but i would rather have a separation of those dependencies on folder level.

Two questions arise:

1. Is this a good way to organize my npm dependencies? If yes, awesome? If no, which I expect:
2. What is a better way to organize my dependencies? Is it possible to specify that **dev** dependencies go into folder **a**, and 'regular' dependencies go into folder b? If so, how do I do this?

In case anyone is wondering, this is the project i am talking about:

https://github.com/michahell/pinbored-webkit

**[updated folder structure to include app.js for clarity]**

Comment: Why thank you for editing my question so quickly @marc_s!

Comment: Most of the work was handled by @mscdex - he got the `dependency` (instead of `dependancy`) fixed before I could...

Comment: I *&%$ allways write that (and some other things) wrong. Will watch out for it :)

Comment: @Michael Did you find a solution yet? I'd like to use the same structure as you do, with dev dependencies outside, and app dependencies inside the App folder, but I'm hesitant to split up my `package.json`

Comment: Hello @Jorn, well no I haven't and I maintain 2 package.json files.. I think I have a script in the (main/dev) package.json that does a cd App && npm install, so you only have to perform npm install once. I still don't like it though... let me know if you find a better solution!

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing now. It works, but meh...

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to keep more than one `package.json` file and multiple `node_module` directories for a project. ***If*** you consider the parts as separate components.

An example might be if, you have one directory containing a node server, another containing a react app, and a third containing some kind of deployment script written in javascript.

Answer (score -6):

@Michael **package.json** file contains all the dependencies related to that project.There is no need for multiple package files and multiple node_modules folders..
**But you need to check where is your App.js file!!**
your **App.js , package.json must be in same folder unless configured**.

Comment: Thanks, @anirudh, i've updated my question according to your answer. My app.js is inside the /App folder and i'd like to keep it that way, all application specific stuff is inside my /App folder!

Comment: @Michael i think you do not need outer package.json and outer node_module folder now!! :)

Comment: i do need that because i am building my node-webkit app with Grunt, and grunt needs npm dependancies (dev dependancies in my case).